# Electron Builder with Angular and Spring

Tags: angular, spring, electron

I am using Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) as OS in development. How can I configure Electron builder to pack my app (with jar of spring that contains my back-end API) into Windows executable machine.
I used the configuration below :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path  = require("path");
const url   = require("url");


let win;

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false
    }
  });
  win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/dist/index.html')

  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  //On Close Event
  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}
```

The problem is that my API calls to the back-end are not passing, so I am wondering what is the right way to do so.

PS: my package.json

```
  "main": "electron-main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "electron-tsc": "tsc main.ts && ng build --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist:linux": "electron-builder --linux",
    "dist:win": "electron-builder --windows"    
  },

  "build": {
    "appId": "com.XXX",

    "asar": false,
    "win": {
      "icon": "../src/assets/img.png",
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon": "../src/assets/img.png",
      "target": "AppImage",
      "category": "Utility"
    }
  }
```

Comment: does it throw any errors when calling the API?

Comment: show me where you call your backend api.

Comment: @FatehMohamed in fact when I run electron in dev mode everything works fine, but when I run dist to pack it I get an executable that shows nothing only blank page, as if it didn't load the resources.

Comment: @tpikachu I have something like:  url = "http://localhost:8080/api/resource/ ..." in my angular service. my basehref is set to "./" in index.html buil.

Comment: @SlimaneDeb Does this app not working after pack?

Comment: @tpikachu yes, but it works fine when I run "ng build --base-href ./ && electron ."

Comment: your backend is jar standalone application right? And where is your backend listening the request. Maybe, you are going to embed this jar file inside this Electron app?

Comment: @tpikachu exactly, with spring boot & spring data rest.